# metric performances varies with each training run of my deep learning model

Tags: keras

My model (a biLSTM model in Keras) gives different results for my test metric (precision) each time I train.

My metric varies between 80% and 92%. That is really bad.

What reason besides a bad kernel initialization could this be?

Answer (score 2):

That difference in results could be from high [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff), the error from sensitivity to small fluctuations in the training set.

Generally, the best solution to high variance is to increase the size of the training dataset.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean variation of training performance or my test performance? My Training performance is stable and almost 1. Test precision varies. My test data consists of a mix of similiar training data and hold out data.

I train now with a kernel seed for my initialization of the kernels but still get different results. I thought the reuslts would be the same if use a seed?

That is really bad for reproducibility.

Comment: I thought high variance (overfitting) is due to the difference in training and test metric. But in my case I also get these diffrent performances with each training run...
I don't mean fluctuations DURING one training.

Comment: I don't mean fluctuations DURING one training. How can I make my model more stable such that I don#t get very different results each time I retrain (of course with same config and data!)

Comment: Reducing the complexity of the model will make the model more stable. The two options are: 1) Reduce the number of parameters 2) Change to a simpler algorithm (e.g., RNN)

Comment: Ok, I know that this will help reducing overfitting. But why should this make the model more reducable? I just worked now for hours because of https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development
and
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2743

Comment: But I still don't get same results on my Laptoop and a google cloud VM. Also I cannot reproduce the the reuslts on my laptop alone! I check for the first epoch. I suppose that you should get the (exact) same result for each epoch for each run? Since random number are seeded...

Comment: That makes me asking: If high variance causes the difference and those comes from random fluctuations, shouldnt it be then the same results after each run since randomness should be same every time? I would suppose small variations are normal, but I have large differences.